# Enabled grid for 2d animation

Tags: snapping, 2d

Absolute beginner here. I would like to make a very simple 2D animation using Blender, but am stuck at the very basic level, I don't even manage to enable a grid. I have searched the internet a lot for guides and video introductions, and found quite a lot of them, but none seem to show what you need to do to enable a grid, and snap-to that grid.

When first opening a new "2D animation", there is a menu at the top that says "Guides", which seems to be intended to enable a grid, but it is greyed out, and selecting something in it does not change anything. After placing a first rectangle, the menu disappears.

So, how can I enable a grid, and enable snap-to the grid in the 2D Animation interface of Blender?

EDIT: Here is what my user interface looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can enable drawing guides and snapping in the *Speed Guides* Menu.

1. Check the small icon to enable it
2. Select the type of guides
3. Enable snapping and adjust the snapping grid size

[image]

You can also enable overlay grid in *Viewport Overlay > Canvas* and change it's appearance in *Viewport Display > Canvas*

[image]

Further reading in Blender Manual:

- [Introduction to drawing](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/introduction.html)
- [Draw Guides](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/guides.html)
- [Drawing Planes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/modes/draw/drawing_planes.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jachym. I had to switch from "Draw" to "Object Mode" to make the icons that you use appear. I can select the "Absolute Grid Snap" in it now, as you show, and the "magnet" icon. That does enable the grid when moving an object, so thanks for that! But it does not enable the grid when drawing an object. Do you know how to enable that?

Comment: Sorry, I totally missed you're talking about 2D animation :). I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I now notice that the "Guides" menu is only visible when I select "Draw" from the side menu, not when I select one of the shapes (Box, Circle, Curve, etc). But even when I select "Draw", the menu is still greyed out as I describe in the question, and selecting something in it does not change any behaviour. Do you know how to enable the Guides menu? And how can I use snap-to grid as well when drawing a Curve, etc?

Comment: Hey :). I'm no 2D animator, I literally just read all this in the blender manual :).

Comment: It looks like for a proper snapping grid, you still need to switch to *Edit mode*. :)

Comment: It looks like Edit mode is mostly 3D transformations, so not that useful for 2D animations :(

Comment: I did find the way to enable this grid menu that you mentioned. You need to first click on the hash icon next to it. So now I can use the guides that you show. Unfortunately, none of the options work like a proper grid, where you can only place points on grid intersections. Well, I probably just have to learn to live with that.

Answer (score 0):

For Blender 2.83.5   you have to be in "2D Animation" or "2D Full Canvas" and in both cases your viewpoint has to be exactly on x,z,y plan(use numpad 7,9,1,3). Otherwise if you move your 3D space view port the grid, in "2D Animation", is gone and in "2D Full Canvas" drops out to a much larger grid

Lachlan

Comment: I understand that. But you should be in "2D Animation" when starting a brand new file with the New > 2D Animation, right? I still don't see a way to enable a proper grid, other than the "Guides" that Jachym shows, and which only work with pencil drawings.